# How do we know that $M_{s-1}/H$ and $N_{r-1}/H$ are simple?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/831504/111520) to a question about proving the Jordan-Hölder Theorem, I think the following fact is used implicitly: let
$$
1 = N_0 \triangleleft \dots \triangleleft N_r = G \hspace{1em} \text{and} \hspace{1em} 1 = M_0 \triangleleft \dots \triangleleft M_s = G
$$
be two composition series of a finite group $G$. Then if we let $H = N_{r-1}\cap M_{s-1}$, we have that $M_{s-1}/H$ and $N_{r-1}/H$ are each simple. But why is that true?

I see that since $M_{s-1}$ and $N_{r-1}$ are each normal in $G$, $H$ is normal in $G$ and hence $H$ is normal in each of $M_{s-1}$ and $N_{r-1}$. However, how does the fact that the quotients are simple follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an isomorphism theorem: For subgroups $H$ and $K$ of a group $G$ with $K$ normal in $G$, $H/H\cap K\cong HK/K$.

Since $M_{s-1}$ and $N_{s-1}$ are maximal normal subgroups, $M_{s-1}N_{r-1}=G$. Therefore, we have $M_{s-1}/H\cong G/N_{r-1}$. The latter quotient group is simple by assumption. Similarly, $N_{r-1}/H\cong G/M_{s-1}$ is simple.